# Pandas comparar valor celda con celda superior e inferior para detectar Outliers

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

¿Podríais indicarme si existe algún método o alguna forma de comparar el valor de una celda con el valor de esa misma celda pero de las filas superior e inferior?

Explico el caso. Tengo un DataFrame que contiene un registro histórico del precio de unos productos (con varios millones de filas de registros). Este dataframe contiene 3 columnas que son el Id, el precio y la fecha. Un ejemplo sería:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"columnid": ["2321fdsf", "2321fdsf",  "2321fdsf", "2321fdsf","3gsdfer3", "4gdsfg44", "4gdsfg44", "4gdsfg44", "4gdsfg44", "7fg45d", "7fg45d", "7fg45d"],
                 "date": ["2022-11-16","2022-11-05","2022-10-29","2022-08-04","2021-09-23","2021-03-06","2021-03-05","2021-02-28","2022-03-05","2022-01-17","2021-12-31"],
                 "precio": [5.2, 5.0, 15.3, 4.8, 3.15, 2.1, 1.8, 3.5, 1.8, 0.1, 0.2, 1.9],
                 })

    columnid      date      precio
0   2321fdsf    2022-11-16  5.20
1   2321fdsf    2022-11-05  5.00
2   2321fdsf    2022-10-29  15.30
3   2321fdsf    2022-08-04  4.80
4   3gsdfer3    2021-09-23  3.15
5   4gdsfg44    2021-03-06  2.10
6   4gdsfg44    2021-03-05  1.80
7   4gdsfg44    2021-02-28  3.50
8   4gdsfg44    2021-01-07  1.80
9   7fg45d      2022-03-05  0.10
10  7fg45d      2022-01-17  0.20
11  7fg45d      2021-12-31  1.90
```

El DF esta ordenado y por producto y fecha, para que salgan los productos juntos ordenados con la fecha más reciente la primera.

El problema que me encuentro es a la hora de poder detectar los posibles outliers. He probado a través de estadísticos (percentiles, media+ desviación típica, múltiplo de la media...) Pero no son muy efectivos, ya que si por ejemplo tengo un producto que no ha subido de precio en 200 registros pero los últimos 5 si, estos 5 los detecta como outlier aunque no lo sean.
La forma que mejor me ha resultado es la de calcularlo mediante un múltiplo de la media del producto, pero tiene sus limitaciones y se deja fuera outliers que sí son, y detecta como outliers precios que están bien.

Entonces se me ha ocurrido que a lo mejor hay una forma de comparar el precio de una fecha con el registro anterior y el siguiente y si hay una evolución muy drástica (como en los ejemplos que he puesto) que lo detecte como Outlier. Ya sea mediante una función lambda o mediante alguna función interna de pandas.

Comment: Buen día, del ejemplo que pusiste en tu pregunta, ¿Podrías agregar un ejemplo de como quedaría el `dataframe` resultante? En el caso de los 200 registros iguales y en los últimos 5 son diferentes, ¿Podrías poner un ejemplo de los 2 valores para ver si hay alguna otra opción de hacerlo?

Comment: Lo mejor es hacer una grafica, si el comportamiento real de los datos ha sido atípico no hay algoritmo que te los distinga (sin mas información).

Comment: Con un df.apply(comparavecinos) y una funcion puedes hacer lo que dices.

Answer (score 0):

Hay una forma muy simple de obtener la diferencia entre cada celda y la anterior. Se trata de usar el método `.diff()` sobre la columna que te interese. El resultado será positivo si el precio subió, o negativo si bajó. Si sólo te interesa saber que cambió, puedes aplicar a continuación `.abs()` al resultado, para quedarte con el valor absoluto.

```
import pandas as pd
data = {"columnid": ["2321fdsf", "2321fdsf",  "2321fdsf", "2321fdsf","3gsdfer3", "4gdsfg44", "4gdsfg44", "4gdsfg44", "4gdsfg44", "7fg45d", "7fg45d", "7fg45d"],
                 "date": ["2022-11-16","2022-11-05","2022-10-29","2022-08-04","2021-09-23","2021-03-06","2021-03-05","2021-02-28","2022-03-05","2022-01-17", "2022-01-19", "2021-12-31"],
                 "precio": [5.2, 5.0, 15.3, 4.8, 3.15, 2.1, 1.8, 3.5, 1.8, 0.1, 0.2, 1.9],
                 }

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df["variacion"] = df.precio.diff().abs()
```

El nuevo dataframe se verá así:

```
    columnid        date  precio  variacion
0   2321fdsf  2022-11-16    5.20        NaN
1   2321fdsf  2022-11-05    5.00       0.20
2   2321fdsf  2022-10-29   15.30      10.30
3   2321fdsf  2022-08-04    4.80      10.50
4   3gsdfer3  2021-09-23    3.15       1.65
5   4gdsfg44  2021-03-06    2.10       1.05
6   4gdsfg44  2021-03-05    1.80       0.30
7   4gdsfg44  2021-02-28    3.50       1.70
8   4gdsfg44  2022-03-05    1.80       1.70
9     7fg45d  2022-01-17    0.10       1.70
10    7fg45d  2022-01-19    0.20       0.10
11    7fg45d  2021-12-31    1.90       1.70
```

Tal vez eso te sirva para probar tu método de detección de outliers. Puedes quedarte por ejemplo con las filas cuya variación haya sido mayor de 10:

```
df[ df.variacion > 10 ]
```

```
   columnid        date  precio  variacion
2  2321fdsf  2022-10-29    15.3       10.3
3  2321fdsf  2022-08-04     4.8       10.5
```